# Best way to display first doc in a view using the UnpBootFormViewer

Tags: android, xpages, teamstudio-unplugged

I am trying to display the first document in a view using the "UnpBootFormViewer".

What I have currently done is include the "UnpBootFlatView" control that references a view which contains only one (1) document (app settings in this instance).  I have it in a "" with the style set to "display: none;".

This works great on a computer using a standard browser, but when the same app is opened on a mobile device (Nexus 5) it does nto work.

Is there a better/easier way to do what I'm trying?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use native document data source. To initialize it with first document from some view you must provide UNID of that document. Example:

```
var v:View = database.getView("view name");
var vec:ViewEntryCollection = v.getAllEntries();
var ve:ViewEntry = vec.getFirstEntry();
var unid = ve.getUniversalID();
return unid;
```

I recommend to use your preferred error catching technique (try/catch, OpenLog...)

Why so complicated - ViewEntryCollection and ViewNavigator collections keep documents sorted as in view. Common beginner's mistake is to use `view.getFirstDocument()` - this document is the first from internal list of documents so it need not to be the first document shown in the view.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is possible and I think it's demostrated in this page from the sample app provided by Teamstudio
[My Activities Page](http://sampler.xcontrols.org/XControls.nsf/MyActivities.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=85257D8E00450BA280257CDD0024CB59&history=true)

This uses the UnpBootFlatView to look up the activities based you your username. It then uses the UnpBootFormViewer to display the first document in the view.

The XPage to reference is MyActivities

The documentations also points out that from release 1.3 of the XControls 'openfirstdocument' is defaulted to 'yes'. If you have this set to anything else the first document in the view will not load.
[Flat View Documentation](http://xcontrols.org/public/docs.html#doc-flatview)

If that's all fine on the standard browser as you suggest and it just doesn't work on the Android device, then I'd suggest contacting [Teamstudio Support.](http://support.teamstudio.com)

Tim C. ;o)

[Disclosure] Tim Clark works for Teamstudio

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  That works for desktop browsers and via the Unplugged app, but not in mobile browsers on iOS and Android when opening the app via a URL :-(